# Regarding i++ and ++i in c++

Tags: c++

There are following two programs for finding largest and secondlargest integers:

1.

```
int main()
{
    int const no_of_elements =10;
    int list[no_of_elements] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 6, 7, 10 };
    int largest = list[0];
    int second_largest = list[0];
    int pos_largest = 0;
    int pos_second_largest = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < no_of_elements; i++)
    {
        if (largest <= list[i])
        {
            second_largest = largest;
            largest = list[i];
            pos_second_largest = pos_largest;
            pos_largest = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Largest number is : " << largest << "\n";
    cout << "And it is at the position : " << ++pos_largest << endl;
    cout << "Second largest number is : " << second_largest << " and its at the position : " << ++pos_second_largest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

2.
In for loop, i do `pos_largest = ++i`
They give different answers:
    1. gives `largest=10 secondlargest=10`      ie as required
    but 2. gives `largest=10 secondlargest=9`

Kindly explain????

Comment: ++i and i++ is i+=1. The former will increase i first then do operation, the later does the operation with i, after that increase its value by 1.

Comment: dont use `++i`, use `i+1` if you want to convert to a count starting at one.

Comment: You cannot find the second largest element in linear time. Imagine the sequence 1, 5, 3. Your program will say 1 is the second largest element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` is post-increment. This means "give me the value of `i`, but after that, increment it".

`++i` is pre-increment. This means "increment `i`, then give me its new value".

```
int i = 1;
int a = i++; // a is now 1, i is 2

i = 1; // reset i's value to 1
int b = ++i; // i's value is incremented to 2, b's value is 2
```

Regarding the `for` loops, both of these have the same effect

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // ...
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

The third section in the for loop is run **after** each iteration (execution) of the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

In your #2, when you hit the first `10` in your list, you assign `pos_largest` to be 6 (i.e,. where 9 is) instead of 5 (where the 10 is) because you've pre-incremented the `i` before the assignment.  Thus, later when you hit the second `10` in your list, it becomes the largest and your second largest is now set to 9 (i.e., the value in spot 6).

Answer (score 1):

`++i` and `i++` is `i+=1`. The former will increase `i` first then does operation, the latter does the operation with `i`, after that increase its value by `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Well your main problem is to understand the difference between ++i (preincrement) and i++ (postincrement). ++i means that it quickly adds the value 1 in the next coming variable or lvalue. And the meaning of the i++ is that it will not add 1 to the previous lvalue or variable untill a sequence point comes. And remember that sequence points are ;  { }  &&  || etc.
e. if you have a code like this.

```
int test=6;
cout<<(test++)<<endl;
cout<<test<<endl;
```

You will be thinking that it will print like this

```
7
7
```

But it will not because it is a post increment. It will not add 1 to test untill a sequence point comes and the next sequence point is   ; . so it will print like this.

```
6
7
```

Opposite is the case for preincrement. It will quickly add 1 to the variable (i.e lvalue otherwise it will give error ) and then display 7 without waiting for the sequence point.

Answer (score 0):

If you use i++ it completes the operation before incrementing the variable. If you use ++i it increments before completing the operation. In most cases you want to use i++, though it greatly depends on how you're using it. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "i = "<< i << endl;
}
```

This will complete the operation, then increment.  However, if you use this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
}
```

it will increment first before printing the value

Comment: I think the 2 **for** loops are the same.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, you're absolutely correct. This was not a good example. I have removed the incorrect outputs, the correct information remains.